# Como funciona o algoritmo de criptografia leve LED?

Tags: algoritmo, segurança, criptografia

Gostaria de entender melhor o funcionamento do algoritmo `LED` passo a passo, principalmente o processo de substituição e permutação dos blocos e principalmente o uso das chaves em cada round.

As chaves em cada round são expansões de uma única chave ou são chaves diferentes?

Já consultei as fontes

1. https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Block_Ciphers#Zorro
2. https://sites.google.com/site/ledblockcipher/design
3. https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/600.pdf

Mas não consegui encontrar se cada round são expansões ou se são chaves diferentes.

Comment: Bem vinda ao StackOverflow em Português =)

Comment: Valeu @Avelino :D

Comment: Não conheço esse algoritmo, mas a primeira referência citada (sobre o LED mesmo, acima da descrição do Zorro) deixa bem claro que ao contrário da maioria das cifras de bloco o LED **não possui** expansão de chaves: "Uma característica interessante desse design é o escalonamento de chaves (ou ausência do mesmo): uma chave de 64 bits tal como está faz o 'ou exclusivo' - xor - com o estado interno, enquanto uma chave de 128 bits é dividida pela metade em duas sub-chaves de 64 bits que são usadas de forma alternada."

Comment: Obrigada pela observação @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou pesquisando também sobre o assunto e lendo no [crypto.SO] achei esta reposta interessante, portanto vou adequar aqui, espero que atenda a nós.

Na página 3 da [Proposta para o Algoritmo LED](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/600.pdf) diz:

> "Note that for a 64-bit key `K`, all subkeys are equal to `K`, while for a 128-bit key `K`, the subkeys are alternatively equal to the left part `K^1` and to the right part `K^2` of `K`."

Traduzindo:

> Observe que para uma chave de 64-bits `k`, todas as sub-chaves são iguais a $k$, enquanto para uma chave de 128-bit `k`, as sub-chaves são alternadamente iguais a parte esquerda de `k^1` e a parte direita `k^2` de de `k`.

Basicamente a entrada da chave principal é dividida em lista ordenadas de *nibbles*, e quando o algoritmo precisa material para sub-chaves ele usa exatamente os *nibbles* diretamente da lista ordenada -- movendo cada *nibble* para o final da linha, para que todos os *nibbles* sejam usados em sucessão. Desde que o algoritmo manipula 64 bits de sub-chaves por vez (16 *nibbles*), para uma chave principal de 64-bit cada sub-chave  será simplesmente a chave principal, e para chaves de 128-bits o algoritmo usará os primeiros 16 *nibbles* da chave master, e então a segunda parte, os 16 *nibbles* restantes, e então o primeiros 16 novamente, e assim por diante. No topo da página 4 mostra o diagrama de como isso funciona para uma chave principal de 80-bits.

Considerando a [pergunta original](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26011) no qual esta resposta foi aplicada, o autor da resposta destaca que as sub-chaves não usadas em '*round*' como destacado na questão, mas que entre cada *passo*, enquanto cada passo é composto de 4 rounds. Cada round consiste de 4 operações, muito similar ao usado no algoritmo AES -- primeiro você executa um **xor** em um round, então você substitui cada *nibble* usando uma operação de substituição não linear (o s-box do *cipher*), você transpõe os *nibbles* passando então através da mais alta permutação difusa linear, com um alto fator de ramificação (similar ao MixColumns no AES, porém optimizado para *nibbles*).

Com base na resposta: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26013